# variable was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

As you can see I get the following error: `'User' was used before it was defined  no-use-before-define` on line **127**:

[image: Screenshot of error]

However, I import it on line **2**:
[image: Screenshot of import]

I just use it as usual on line **127**:
[image: Screenshot of me using my variable]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your variable from User to user. I suspect that it is confused that you have both a variable and an object you are trying to create using the same name. You could alternatively change the namespace import to something other than User.

Comment: You're brilliant, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use the same variable name as the import name - that is causing the conflict.
You can use `import as` if you want to keep the name of the const variable as USER only.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can't believe I missed that :(